# Angular2 cli: dynamic urls in scss files based on environment

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I'm building a projects using angular cli, how can I manipulate urls in css/scss files based on environment? i.e so that I can have something like this in development:

```
 background-image: url(url1/foo.png);
 @font-face { font-family: foo;
    src: url(url1/foo.woff);
}
```

and have that translated to the following by running 'ng build --prod':

```
 background-image: url(produrl/foo.png);
 @font-face { font-family: foo;
    src: url(produrl/foo.woff);
}
```